# Relative column width in LaTeX

Tags: tables, columns

How can I define a tabular with two columns in LaTeX, where the first column fills 30% of the page width and the second column fills the rest?

Comment: I guess you meant the "second _column_" and not the "second tabular", right? I corrected that for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package.

For example:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
...
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.3\textwidth}X}
...
\end{tabularx}
```

`tabularx` has the advantage, that you can specify the whole width and use `X` type columns which fill up the remaining space.

Answer (score 5):

You could try something likes this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr.3\textwidth}p{\dimexpr.7\textwidth-4\tabcolsep}}
some text some text some text &  some text some text some text text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text   text text text text text text text text text 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The first column takes 30% of the `\textwidth`; the second column takes `.7\textwidth` minus 4 times `\tabcolsep` (the space between the column and its contents).