# How can i set the width of a table?

Tags: tables

How can i set the minimum width of a table?  I want to have a series of tables that are all the same width?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would use the [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package. An argument to the `tabularx` environment specifies the table width, X columns share the available space.

A simple example:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{lXXr}
left column & text & text & right column
\end{tabularx}
```

See also:

- [Relative column width in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14437/relative-column-width-in-latex)
- [How to force a table into page width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-force-a-table-into-page-width)

Comment: @user1709076 It's setting the table width depending on the text width, as 80% of the current text width.

Comment: is there any way to set the width of the table in inches?

Comment: @user1709076 Sure, such as \begin{tabularx}{4in}{lXXr}

Answer (score 12):

Use a `tabular*` environment, with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`, as in

```
\begin{tabular*}{.5\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc}
  One& Two& Three\\
  Four& Five& Six
\end{tabular*}
```

(where you replace `.5\linewidth` with something wide enough for all of the tables).