# How to set table size to \linewidth without using a package such as tabularx?

Tags: tables, width

PLOS journals provide the following [instructions](http://www.plosbiology.org/static/latexGuidelines.action) for preparing a LaTeX manuscript:

> 1. Do NOT use any other packages than
>      those specified in the template. If
>      you use any other packages, your
>      manuscript will be returned.
> 2. Please
>      limit the use of macros. The
>      conversion software we use often
>      cannot handle even "simple" macros,
>      which then increase the chance for
>      errors in the converted document.

The [template](http://www.plosbiology.org/static/plos_template.tex) only uses the packages: `amsmath`, `amssymb`, `graphicx`, `cite`, and `color`.

Here is an example of the table that I would like to include in my document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color} 
\topmargin 0.0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.5cm
\evensidemargin 0.5cm
\textwidth 16cm 
\textheight 21cm
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright]{caption}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{\bf{Test Table}}
  \begin{tabular*}{1\linewidth}{@\extracolsep{\fill}}{rllllrrrlllll}
    \hline
    & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 \\ 
    \hline
    & Rowname & something  & 1000000 & 200 & 3000 & 40 &   1.5 & 320000 & 5.8 & 80 &  $^\ast$   \\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular*}
\begin{flushleft}
caption text caption text
\end{flushleft}
\label{tab:priors}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to adapt the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16766/how-can-i-set-the-width-of-a-table/16770#16770) to a previous question along the lines of: `\begin{tabular*}{.5\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rllllrrrlllll}`, but this does not work.

Comment: `tabularx` is part of the [**required**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/) packages of LaTeX and therefore part of LaTeX (2e that is). Apparently they don't use (La)TeX but some "conversion software" to convert it to something else. Really a shame! But all of this doesn't help you.

Comment: Please don't use `\bf` in modern LaTeX documents. The correct macro is `\textbf{...}`. See [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it) for an explanation. Apart from this `\bf{...}` is wrong (if you using the default definition) and should be `{\bf ...}`.

Comment: @Martin PLOS apparently has a few other really stupid restrictions, such as “no vector graphics” (only TIFF). The “best practices” are basically a list of LaTeX “don’t”s.

Comment: @Konrad: I'm not surprised. I assume it is nearly impossible to change their minds about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to make the total width of the table equal to `\linewidth` and to have the columns evenly spaced, then you can reduce the font for the table (using, for example, `\fontsize` as in my example code), then set the inter-column space to `0pt` (redefining `\tabcolsep`), and then use

```
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllrrrllll}
```

(there was an error in your code).

I also suppressed the commands depending on the `caption` package since it is not on the list of "accdepted" packages, and increased the vertical space between rows (redefining `\arraystretch`):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color} 
\topmargin 0.0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.5cm
\evensidemargin 0.5cm
\textwidth 16cm 
\textheight 21cm

\date{}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize
\caption{Test Table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllrrrllll}
    \hline
    Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 & Column1 \\ 
    \hline
    Rowname & something  & 1000000 & 200 & 3000 & 40 &   1.5 & 320000 & 5.8 & 80 &  $^\ast$   \\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular*}\par\medskip
text caption text
\label{tab:priors}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error in your code. It should be:

```
\begin{tabular*}{1\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rllllrrrlllll}
```

not

```
\begin{tabular*}{1\linewidth}{@\extracolsep{\fill}}{rllllrrrlllll}
```

This gives you the following table. Note that your example content is to wide for `\linewidth`.

[image: Result]

You didn't states what result you really want (i.e. how the table should be aligned etc.), so I can't tell if this is all you need. An alternative option would be to just typeset the table in its natural width and center it using `\centering`.